Auth session exchange inside React IFrame to python plotly-dash
I have two separate app authenticate with same Auth0 domain with two client IDs. I want to integrate one inside the other using iframe. I am using reactjs for Iframe and my other application is Python dash app. Do i need to do some additional configurations from Aouth0 or can i use basic Aouth0 app for both.
import React from "react";

const MyIFrame: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <iframe
      src={`http://localhost:8090/`}
      title="Authenticated Iframe"
      width="100%"
      height="1200px"
      sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-forms allow-popups"
      referrerPolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"
      frameBorder="none"
    />
  );
};

export default MyIFrame;

This is my dash + flask app
@app.callback(Output("page-content", "children"),
              Input("url", "pathname"))
def display_page(pathname):
    print("Current session data:", session)
    if 'user' not in session:
        return dcc.Location(href="/login", id="redirect-login")
    if pathname == "/":
        return base_layout
    else:
        return html.Div("404 Page Not Found") 


oauth = OAuth(app.server)
oauth.register(
    "auth0",
    client_id=os.getenv("AUTH0_CLIENT_ID"),
    client_secret=os.getenv("AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET"),
    client_kwargs={
        "scope": "openid profile email",
        'state': False
    },
    server_metadata_url=f'https://{os.getenv("AUTH0_DOMAIN")}/.well-known/openid-configuration',
    state=None,
)

@app.server.route("/login")
def login():
    return oauth.auth0.authorize_redirect(redirect_uri=url_for("callback", _external=True))

@app.server.route("/callback", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def callback():
    token = oauth.auth0.authorize_access_token()
    session["user"] = token  # Store user token in session
    return redirect("/")

@app.server.route("/logout")
def logout():
    session.clear()
    return redirect(
        "https://" + os.getenv("AUTH0_DOMAIN")
        + "/v2/logout?"
        + urlencode(
            {
                "returnTo": url_for("home", _external=True),
                "client_id": os.getenv("AUTH0_CLIENT_ID"),
            },
            quote_via=quote_plus,
        )
    )


refere to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79137950/csrf-warning-token-exchange-failed-with-mismatching-state-using-flask-dash-auth
