CSRF Warning: Token Exchange Failed with mismatching_state using Flask-Dash Auth0 inside React iFrame
I'm working on a Python Dash project with Flask and Auth0 for authentication. The project works fine when accessed directly. However, when I load it inside a React project using an iframe, I encounter a continuous redirect loop after a successful login. Auth0 logs show successful logins for both the Dash and React apps, but the browser console shows the following error:

Token exchange failed mismatching_state: CSRF Warning! State not equal in request and response.

Python Dash (Flask) Setup
from authlib.integrations.flask_client import OAuth
from flask_cors import CORS

oauth = None

def setup_auth(app):
    global oauth
    oauth = OAuth(app)
    oauth.register(
        "auth0",
        client_id=app.server.config['AUTH0_CLIENT_ID'],
        client_secret=app.server.config['AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET'],
        client_kwargs={"scope": "openid profile email", 'state': False},
        server_metadata_url=f'https://{app.server.config["AUTH0_DOMAIN"]}/.well-known/openid-configuration',
        state=None
    )
    return oauth

def setup_CORS(app):
    server = app.server
    allowed_origins = app.server.config['ALLOWED_ORIGINS'].split(',')
    CORS(server, resources={r"/*": {"origins": allowed_origins}})

import os
from urllib.parse import quote_plus, urlencode
from flask import redirect, url_for, session

def setup_auth_routes(app, oauth):
    @app.server.route("/callback", methods=["GET", "POST"])
    def callback():
        try:
            token = oauth.auth0.authorize_access_token()
            session["user"] = token
        except Exception as e:
            return redirect("/login")
        return redirect("/")

    @app.server.route("/logout")
    def logout():
        session.clear()
        return redirect(
            "https://" + app.server.config["AUTH0_DOMAIN"]
            + "/v2/logout?"
            + urlencode(
                {
                    "returnTo": url_for("/", _external=True),
                    "client_id": app.server.config["AUTH0_CLIENT_ID"],
                },
                quote_via=quote_plus,
            )
        )

    @app.server.route("/silent-auth")
    def silent_auth():
        return oauth.auth0.authorize_redirect(
            redirect_uri=os.getenv("SILENT_CALLBACK_URL"),
            prompt='none'
        )

    @app.server.route("/silent-callback", methods=["GET", "POST"])
    def silent_callback():
        token = oauth.auth0.authorize_access_token()
        session["user"] = token
        return redirect("/")

    @app.server.route("/login")
    def login():
        return oauth.auth0.authorize_redirect(os.getenv("CALLBACK_URL"))

@app.callback(Output("page-content", "children"), Input("url", "pathname"))
def display_page(pathname):
    if 'user' not in session:
        return dcc.Location(href="/login", id="redirect-login")
    if pathname == "/":
        return home_layout
    else:
        return html.Div("404 Page Not Found")

React Component with iFrame
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const MyComponent: React.FC = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
  
  const refreshSession = () => {
    const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
    if (iframe && iframe.contentWindow) {
      iframe.src = "https://example.com/silent-auth";
    }
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      refreshSession();
    }, 10 * 60 * 1000); 

    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, []);
  
  const handleIframeLoad = () => {
    setLoading(false); 
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ position: "relative", width: "100%", paddingBottom: "56.25%" }}>
      {loading && <div>Loading iframe...</div>}
      <iframe
        src="https://example.com"
        title="Authenticated Iframe"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        style={{ position: "absolute", top: 0, left: 0, border: "none" }}
        sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-forms allow-popups"
        referrerPolicy="no-referrer"
        loading="lazy"
        onLoad={handleIframeLoad}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;

Issue
On local development, it works fine. But when I deploy it on AWS, the redirect loop occurs, and the Auth0 logs show a successful login. But looping with a CSRF warning for mismatching state.
What I’ve Tried
Verified that both applications use the same domain and correct callback URLs.
Adjusted the Auth0 settings to include silent authentication.
Ensured the state parameter is disabled on client_kwargs as shown above.
Question
How can I resolve the mismatching_state: CSRF Warning! error when embedding my Flask-Dash app with Auth0 authentication inside an iframe in my React project? Any suggestions on configuring the state parameter correctly or handling the silent authentication approach?

The provided code is working fine, and no changes are needed. However, when testing the iframe application on localhost over HTTP, it doesn’t work. Both applications are on the HTTPS and use the same identity server works fine with different clients
